# How rename input class in crispy-form Dlango

Tags: python, django, django-crispy-forms

How rename input class "numberinput form-control"?

```
<input type="number" name="sq" step="0.1" class="numberinput form-control" required="" id="id_sq">
```

I can rename div class, lable class, but not input

```
class ProjectForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ["file", "sq", "rent_tax"]
```

Template

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-0">
  {{ form_project.sq|as_crispy_field }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

Using Javascript

```
document.getElementById('id_sq').className = 'css-class';
```

in settings.py

```
CRISPY_CLASS_CONVERTERS = {'numberinput': "css-class"}
```

https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/crispy_tag_forms.html#change-crispy-forms-input-default-classes

or

refer https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/forms/fields/

```
class ProjectForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ["file", "sq", "rent_tax"]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProjectForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # adding html attributes
        self.fields['sq'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'css-class'
```

Comment: My form is big. In my example, just an excerpt of the entire code. CRISPY_CLASS_CONVERTERS, it's rename all input number fields. I need rename only 2 fields. With __init__ Unfortunately, there has been no change

Comment: @nikar try using javascript